# Xammp error while starting apache and mysql services

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, xampp

I installed XAMPP on my sister's computer and I have no clue as to why apache and mysql won't start. I thought that it had to do with her firewall but I have turned it off and it still refuses to start up.

Have attached a screenshot of the error.

[image]

I have tried installing WAMP Server too and even that refused to start up.

**Edit:** The computer is running Windows 7

Comment: For clarity: Which version of Windows is that?

Comment: @Tobias: The computer is running Windows 7

Comment: Do you have administrator rights on the machine? You need to be an admin to start and stop services on Windows.

Comment: Building on Ian's question: Does starting it without the SVC checkmark work?

Comment: @Ian: The XAMPP control invokes a UAC prompt when you install the service.

Comment: yup I am the admin of the pc @lan C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much ado that is after multiple re-installations, poking and probing through error logs and minutely studying the firewall, I decided that there must be something else that was wrong and hence I decided to check her hosts file (didn't expect it to be the worry as I didn't think she would have reached there) and there was the culprit. localhost was pointing to an IP that didn't exist in that network. Apparently, she had loaned out her PC for a few days to a friend and that's where it might have happened (*well 'A Friend in Need is a Friend Indeed)* ;)

Anyways deleting that entry that solved the problem, posting this answer as it solved the problem and just in case anyone over looks the hosts file being edited possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Apache has an error log. Look there for details.

Answer (score 1):

My friend had the same problem. Most likely another program is using port 80. Run a Port-Check and find out what's using that port.